# Why Cant I Save More Than 2 New Entries To A LocalStorage Key in a given session?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, local-storage

I have a script that currently iterates over some objects in an array and downloads a file from a "url" property on the object. When the download finishes I add that object to a different array and persist it to the localstorage.

Lets say that i have 50 files that I need to download. If I start the app and it starts download them and processes more than 2. Only 2 new Objects are added to the localstorage. Even thought the other files have actually downloaded.

```
var App = {
    settings: {
        apiKey: null,
        username: null,
        websites: [],
        activeWebsite: null,
        validManifest: false,
        manifest: {}
    },
    manifestChanges: {
        raw: {},
        totalFileChanges: 0,
        totalFilesProcessed: 0,
        totalFilesToAdd: 0,
        totalFilesAdded: 0,
        totalFilesToReplace: 0,
        totalFilesReplaces: 0,
        totalFilesToRemove: 0,
        totalFilesRemoved: 0
    },
}
```

Then in App I have a function that calls this bit of code

```
StorageManager.downloadFile(file.remoteUrl,function(progressEvent){
    var filePercent = 100;
    if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
        filePercent = progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100
    }
    App.loadPage('progress',{
        'heading': 'Downloading New Files',
        'mainTitle': 'Total Progress ('+App.manifestChanges.totalFilesAdded+'/'+App.manifestChanges.totalFilesToAdd+')',
        'mainPercent':  Math.floor(App.manifestChanges.totalFilesAdded / App.manifestChanges.totalFilesToAdd * 100),
        'secondaryTitle': 'File Progress: '+property,
        'secondaryPercent': Math.floor(filePercent)
    });
},function(){
    console.log('saved out: '+property);
    App.manifestChanges.totalFilesAdded++;
    App.manifestChanges.raw.add[property]['finished'] = true;
    $.extend(true, App.settings, StorageManager.getSettings());
    App.settings.manifest[property] = file;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(App.settings.manifest[property]));
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(StorageManager.saveSettings(App.settings)){
            App.loadPage('progress',{
                'heading': 'Downloading New Files',
                'mainTitle': 'Total Progress ('+App.manifestChanges.totalFilesAdded+'/'+App.manifestChanges.totalFilesToAdd+')',
                'mainPercent':  Math.floor(App.manifestChanges.totalFilesAdded / App.manifestChanges.totalFilesToAdd * 100)
            });
            App.handleManifestAdd(cb);
        }
        else{
            alert('Failed to update manifest after saving: '+property);
        }
    },500);
})
```

The StorageManager:

```
var StorageManager = {
    getSettings: function () {
        console.log('getting settings');
        if (typeof window.localStorage !== 'undefined') {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('AppSaSettings'));
        }
        else {
            console.log('local storage not defined');
            return {};
        }
    },
    saveSettings: function (newSettings) {
        if (typeof window.localStorage !== 'undefined') {
            localStorage.setItem('AppSaSettings', JSON.stringify(newSettings));
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    },
    downloadFile: function (url, progressCb, finishCb) {
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        var uri = encodeURI(url);
        var urlParts = uri.split('/');
        fileTransfer.download(
            uri,
            StorageManager.downloadsFolder + urlParts[urlParts.length -     1],
            function (entry) {
                finishCb(entry.toURL());
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
                finishCb(false);
            },
            true
        );
        fileTransfer.onprogress = progressCb;
    }
}
```

The time out was in there to see if it was an Async issue. I have been trying everything i can think of under the sun trying to figure out why it wont save more that 2 updates. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: which OS and device. For Andorid 5.1 which uses chromium webview 42, localstorage will not persist

Comment: Android 5.02, not sure where to see webview version, cordova version 4.3. The localstorage is persisting though, its just not persisting everything.

Comment: settings->apps->downloaded->android system webview(or)chromium webview
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=479767